# Draw multiple objects in one glDrawElements()

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm practicing in basic things in OpenGL ES2.0 using this 2d tutorial:
http://androidblog.reindustries.com/a-real-opengl-es-2-0-2d-tutorial-part-2/

Basically it just draws a rect with a texture.
Now I would like to draw multiple rects in one `glDrawElements()` call on different positions but with the same texture. So I add more items to the `vertices` and `indices` arrays. However texture coords (`uvs` array) are the same for every rect and there's no sense to stretch it by copying the same values. Can I somehow reuse it or perhaps set it as a constant somewhere inside the shader code?

Vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
  v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );
}
```

Arrays (used in buffers):

```
vertices = new float[]
{  10.0f, 200f, 0.0f,
   10.0f, 100f, 0.0f,
   100f, 100f, 0.0f,
   100f, 200f, 0.0f,
};

indices = new short[] {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};

uvs = new float[] {
      0.0f, 0.0f,
      0.0f, 1.0f,
      1.0f, 1.0f,
      1.0f, 0.0f
  };
```

Render code:

```
private void Render() {
  GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  int mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
  GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
  GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);

  int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord" );
  GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLoc );
  GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, uvBuffer);

  int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uMVPMatrix");
  GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, m, 0);

  int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (program, "s_texture" );
  GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc, 0);

  GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

  GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
  GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);
}
```

Comment: In ES 2.0, there isn't really anything much better than replicating the texture coordinates. In ES 3.0 or later, you could use instanced rendering.

Comment: @RetoKoradi, sad to hear that, many thanks anyway!